# JaCoCo agent Configuration in Weblogic | ClassCastException in server startup

Tags: weblogic, jacoco

Trying to configure JaCoCo agent in Weblogic 11g, after giving below mention parameter

-XXaggressive -Xmx8192m -Xms8192m -Xgc:pausetime -Xgc:gencon -XXnosystemgc -Duser.home=/scratch/app/product/fmw/XXXinstall/XXX/config -Dsun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout=10000
-javaagent:/scratch/app/product/fmw/user_projects/domains/host_domain/lib/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=/scratch/app/product/fmw/user_projects/domains/host_domain/tmp/host_jacoco.exec,output=tcpserver,address=,includes=com.*

WEBLOGIC SERVER IS NOT COMING UP PROPERLY FOR BELOW MENTION LOGS

**Error**

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Z
        at XXX.app.AbstractApplication.fetchAllOverriddenServices(AbstractApplication.java:1000)
        at XXX.app.AbstractApplication.checkAccess(AbstractApplication.java:930)
        at XXX.app.sms.service.provider.AccessibleResourceApplicationService.initializeRequestedResource(AccessibleResourceApplicationService.java:1011)
        at XXX.app.sms.service.provider.AccessibleResourceLoader.initializeSingleton(AccessibleResourceLoader.java:187)
        at XXX.app.sms.service.provider.AccessibleResourceLoader.loadResources(AccessibleResourceLoader.java:232)
        at XXX.app.adapter.impl.sms.AccessibleResourceLoaderAdapter.loadResources(AccessibleResourceLoaderAdapter.java:49)
        at XXX.app.bootstrap.BootstrapInitializer.initializeSecuritySingletons(BootstrapInitializer.java:292)
        at XXX.channel.branch.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.init(BootstrapServlet.java:46)

**Note : After removing parameter :**

-javaagent:/scratch/app/product/fmw/user_projects/domains/host_domain/lib/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=/scratch/app/product/fmw/user_projects/domains/host_domain/tmp/host_jacoco.exec,output=tcpserver,address=,includes=com.*

**Server is coming up properly.**

Answer (score 0):

As was answered in https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/567 :

> WebLogic server without applications starts perfectly with JaCoCo.

Most likely you have an issue in your code:

> To collect execution data JaCoCo adds members to the classes. One of those members is a field with type `boolean[]` (`[Z` in bytecode notation). These members are [marked as `synthetic`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Member.html#isSynthetic()). Your application and its libraries must ignore synthetic members. If they are not ignored, then change you application to do so, or exclude classes from instrumentation using agent parameters `includes` and `excludes`.
>
> Run your application under debugger, put a breakpoint at line `XXX.app.AbstractApplication.fetchAllOverriddenServices(AbstractApplication.java:1000)` and investigate why there is wrong cast or/and which classes to exclude. Or start excluding packages of your application one by one.